# How to get all rows and store it into single row based on duplicate column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Table like below:

```
Id  Name   Email
1    A     email1@gmail.com
2    B     email1@gmail.com
3    C     email1@gmail.com
4    d     email2@gmail.com
5    E     email3@gmail.com
6    F     email3@gmail.com
```

Expected output(while searching from an email)

```
Id    Name1  Name2   Name3  Email

1     A      B       C      email1@gmail.com
```

How to get this result using mysql query?

Comment: Have you tried anything???

Comment: No i am trying anything can you please guide me

Answer (score 2):

using while loop you can display like you want

```
while($dbrow = mysql_fetch_row($dbx))
{
    print("<tr>");
    $col_num = 0;

    foreach($dbrow as $key=>$value){
        if($dbrow[$col_num] > 0)
        {
              print("<td>$dbrow[$col_num]</td>");
        }
        else 
        {
            print("<td> </td>");
        }
     $col_num++;
     }
  print("</tr>");
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your reply. while using the above code if i am not giving no condition means  it returns all the records but if i give conditions like email id means it returns the records 1,2,3 only. but this is not am expected. please guide me

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Name), Email
FROM table
WHERE 1
GROUP BY Email
```

You can have the Names as comma separated string, then parse it as per your need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. it is usefull . is this any posible to store the name columns into name1,name2,name3 . please guide me

Comment: I want to split the values from one column to separate how to do that can you please help me